# libxml2 htmlSaveFileEnc saves utf8 chars as &#1043;

Tags: c, utf-8, libxml2

I am trying to save utf8 encoded html with libxml2, it works fine, but non ascii characters saved as `&#1043;`. Code used to save file:

```
htmlSaveFileEnc("modified.html", docPtr, "utf8");
```

How can I prevent this and save it as

> Г

utf8 character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround use [`htmlDocContentDumpOutput()`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLtree.html#htmlDocContentDumpOutput) function. Dump document content to char buffer and write the buffer to file.

```
//htmlSaveFileEnc("modified.html", docPtr, "utf8");
xmlOutputBufferPtr out = xmlAllocOutputBuffer(NULL);
if (out) {
  htmlDocContentDumpOutput(out, docPtr, "utf8");
  const xmlChar *buffer = xmlBufferContent((xmlBuffer *) out->buffer);       
  // write buffer to file
  FILE *file = fopen("modified.html", "w");
  fputs((char *) buffer, file);
  fclose(file);

  xmlOutputBufferClose(out);
}
```